# NSDate on iOS Issues

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, uilocalnotification

I absolutely hate NSDate.  Just when I think I have my head wrapped around it, DST either starts or ends, and wrecks everything I am working on.

I am parsing an XML file which in the pubDate has:

```
Fri, 1 Aug 2014 20:15:00 -0500
```

The event occurs at 8:15 PM in the Central time zone.  This would normally be -0600, but due to taking place during DST, it becomes -0500.

Anyways, since this is just a string of text in the XML, I use NSDateFormatter to format it to an NSDate, and then store it as a property of a class I created:

```
NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"pubDate"];
NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822];
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *dateofarticle = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:articleDate];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateofarticle];
```

I have this date appear in the detailTextLabel of a TableView cell, and it shows perfectly as 8:15 PM using:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter3 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter3 setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [formatter3 setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *detailstext = [formatter3 stringFromDate:entry.articleDate];
    cell.detailLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - Tap for more details.", detailstext];
```

So far, all is well.  I have the time of 8:15 PM from the XML, and it shows 8:15 PM in the TableView.  It is when setting a reminder that things get screwy.

I make the property self.theDate in my reminder class equal the same articleDate I have saved from the first part of all this, and then run this code:

```
NSDate *newDate = [self.thedate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*15];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter3 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        [formatter3 setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
        [formatter3 setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
       UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.timeZone = nil;
        notification.fireDate = newDate;
```

From all this, I would expect it to fire at 8:00 PM on August 1st, but when I schedule notification and then change the time on my phone to this date, it fires one hour too late, at 9:00 PM.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It doesn't matter what it prints out in an NSLog because Console automatically adjusts an NSDate to the computer's time zone.

Comment: To make it fire at that time no matter what time zone

Comment: 2014-08-02 01:00:00 +0000

Comment: As it says in my original post Fri, 1 Aug 2014 20:15:00 -0500, edited to be 15 minutes earlier.  To paraphrase you....Did you bother to read my original post?

Comment: Have you tried printing the date after you try to remove 15 mins from it?